# Regex to accept one or more characters before @

Tags: c#, regex, email-address

I have the following email REGEX validation.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)([a-zA-Z0-9])@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})
```

when I test it doesn't allow emails with single character before @.e.g t@stackoverflow.com but it allows 2 characters before @ .  e.g th@stackoverflow.com
.So please can someone show where do I go wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: this regex should work :)  http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: TLD may have much more than 4 character, see: http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Answer (score 2):

Second group should have quantitifier that allows 0 characters. This seems to [resolve](http://regexr.com/?38987) the issue:

```
...([a-zA-Z0-9]*)@...
```

**Update.** As @Nyx noted in comment, the above will match `address.@themail.com`. If this is to be avoided, you can apply `zero or more` quantitifier to the first group, and `one or more` to the second:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@...
```

Comment: I think the * should be applied to the first group instead, otherwise you could be able to type me.@gmail.com with a . before the @.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.].*@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})
```

But its a bad idea to validate regex.

Why?

Check out the article:http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The first part expects 1 or more characters because of the **+** :

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)
```

And the second 1 character :

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])
```

So in the end that makes 2 or more characters.